# Two different encoding in same Eclipse workspace?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, encoding, utf-8

This might sound like a really weird question.

In my new Eclipse Workspace I have the default encoding set to `UTF-8` (Windows > Pref.. > Workspace > UTF8). But I have an old android roject that lays in another Workspace which had default encoding of `CP1252`. When I import my old android project into my new workspace, it seems that when I build this project to the device all 'Å', 'Ä', 'Ö' characters becomes square-shaped question-marks (typical for when encoding is wrong).

I thought having the default encoding in the new workspace to UTF-8 wouldn't cause this kind of issues. What can I do and what might be causing my issues?

Thank you!

Comment: have you checked what encoding is being used by the project after you import it? `properties->resources`

Comment: Open each of your files in a **decent text editor** (which means `!= NotePad`), and save each one as **UTF-8**.

Comment: @Paizo Yes, it says "inherited from container (UTF-8)".

Comment: @Der Golem I tried this with one file, just to test it. But it didn't do anything since it seems it's already UTF-8. :/

Comment: And does your layout have the UTF-8 declaration in the header?

Comment: ... which is **this one**: `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>`

Comment: @DerGolem: Notepad supports loading and saving UTF-8 encoded files.

Comment: Can't understand why I would receive down-votes on this question. It seems that when I import my old project into the new workspace it modifies the mentioned characters to square-shaped question-marks (inside the actual textfile). In other words if I manually change the wrong characters to correct once more it will work. But that's hell of a lot work.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the best solution, will be copy & paste all your code to a new project in your new workspace. Maybe will take less time to do this that find a "possible" solution to your issue, if your project is not too big.